# Width Customization using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for asking this type of ques. But i want to know that I have a `Parent Div` with `height` and `width` as `100px` It looks like square. Is there is a way to customize the width alone like `top-width` and `bottom-width`

For example
`width` is applicable for `left to right` and `height` is applicable for `top to bottom`
If `top-width is zero` and `bottom width is 100` ,`height is 100` then it looks like `triangle`
Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pDdKm/3/)**
The same way i want to do with different shape. Is there is Possible to achieve that in css.
Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Can you add an image to show the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to do that , instead for making tringles or shapes like trapezium we 
use border-width like this in fiddle:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
    margin:20px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qbGX/

we make the main content of the div as 0 height and 0 width.
and then use the border-width to do the trick .

The trick is that, the borders meet at corners like those in photo frames. so if we make two borders invisible and reduce the size of one . it will form a shape of a triangle.
for more details you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work?rq=1) question on so.

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can i make the content appear inside the triangle shape.http://jsfiddle.net/7qbGX/2/

Answer (score 3):

Well, things like that do not exist in CSS. There are some tricks like using the :before and :after selectors to combine multiple elements to make things look like expected, see [this list of shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), but they won't behave as you might expect. Things like the text flow will not work in that shape without making use of a bit of Javascript.

Comment: I'm still rubbing my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Found this very interesting post, thanks to your interesting question:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDdKm/4/)

```
#sample {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 120px solid green;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

and [source](http://www.css3shapes.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do so using your way. However there is the `transform` property that might help in achieving what you want although you still need to play around with it. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) or [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for further details :)